# Export an email from Outlook to PDF?

Tags: ms-office, pdf

Is there way to export a specific email from Mac Office 2011 in PDF (or some other portable document format)?

I don't want to export a whole archive, just a particular e-mail to attach to a ticket.  External services are not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Can't you just print it and select "Save as PDF" in the Print dialog?

Comment: @patrix Can you make that an answer please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the "Save as PDF" option in the Print dialog (drop down is in lower left corner of the dialog window).

Answer (score 0):

Export an email from Outlook to PDF? you should read this technet article, which helps you save your Outlook PST mails as PDF format. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Convert-PST-to-PDF-with-25f19205

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.